# HTTP requests in python with basic authentication

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests, basic-authentication

I have a piece of code that includes several `GET` requests. I have a simple if statement to check the status code and provide `auth` if I receive a status code of `401`. How do I avoid having a separate if statement for every single request line I have?

I'd like to be able to provide credentials only once if its protected instead of having to provide it with every single request.

EDIT - Added some code for reference
      response = requests.get(self.uri + '/v2/apps')

```
    if (response.status_code == 401):
        print("It appears that your marathon instance is protected, please enter your username and password")
        usr = input("Username: ")
        pwd = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
        response = requests.get(self.uri + '/v2/apps', auth=(usr,pwd)).json()
```

Comment: Show us some code. Your question is very vague.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what you'd want to achieve here, but if you wan't to avoid the username and password inputs each time, I suggest you store them in variables outside this scope. But the better solution would be to create a config file in `.py` or `.json` and read it from there during your initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you get a status code of 401, it means you're not authorized to use the resource.

Second, you have different options for authenticating the client once. Usually, I recommend looking into using HTTPS for transporting the data. You can use:

- You can use a cookie with expiry
- Using a token service in your web server

There multiple authentication standards (e.g. SAML, OAuth, OpenId, etc.) already existing, try not to reinvent the wheel.